# Record a video or audio with Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

My Blazor WebAssembly application has to record feedback from clients and save them in a file on the server. In order to do that, I want to add a function for recording a video or an audio. That means the application has to have the permission to use camera and microphone.

Also, this function has to work cross-platform (iOS, Android and web in general).

Is there any limitation with iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use **Javascript Interop** for this.  There are some Blazor-specific examples out there, and when those fail, you'll have to search for JS code.

You will want to find examples for the **MediaRecorder API**, which as you can see is now supported by most platforms, including iOS: https://caniuse.com/?search=mediarecorder

You will want to:

1. Check if the browser HAS an audio device
2. Initalize an instance of Mediarecorder (this will automatically popup a permissions request)
3. Once it's done, do something with the buffer (like convert it to a blob for immediate playback, or to .mp3)
4. Either transfer the file through C#, or upload it to an MVC-style API.  I chose the latter, and it is simple and works fine.

Unfortunately, I can't give a full working example without revealing some clever trickery that I want to keep to myself (I run an English learning site).  But if you have specific issues, I'll be happy to help.